# JMS serializer yml datetime format

Tags: symfony, serialization, yaml, jmsserializerbundle

I have an Rest API built on Symfony 2.7 Framework with FOSRestBundle and **JMSSerializerBundle**. I have a look to yml [reference](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/yml_reference) and [annotations](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations).

I have choosen to define how each entity of my model is serialized **with yml**.

I have seen that we can serialize `Datetime` object on a specific format :

```
@JMS\Type("DateTime<'d-m-Y'>")
```

But **I don't know the correct syntax used with yml definition**, I have tried :

```
my_field:
  expose: true
  type: datetime
  format: 'd-m-Y'
```

**And**

```
my_field:
  expose: true
  type: datetime<'d-m-Y'>
```

I don't want to use `Annotations` because I have a lot of yaml files.

But **the field is not serialized**...

Anyone can help me ?

Comment: did you try?: `type:  "DateTime<'d-m-Y'>"` or `type:  "DateTime('d-m-Y')"`

Comment: The correct answer is `DateTime<'d-m-Y'>`, thanks for the help !

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I put it as an answer in case it helps more people:

```
my_field:
  expose: true
  type: DateTime<'d-m-Y'>
```